# How to correctly reference an item in a list of lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to reference an item in a list of lists, but it's only spitting back out a number in the item and not the whole item itself. Let me show what I mean.

```
# Let's say I have this list here
L = [['201','304','514'],['312','143','224']]
```

If i were to do this

```
L2 = L[0]
print(L2[0])
```

The result should be 
    '201'
Correct?

Well in this case my program is shooting only a 2 back out to me which is the first number of the item. Here is some of my code.

```
zp = [list(t) for t in zip(*[iter(masterL)] * 3)]
# masterL is just a regular list and zp creates a list of lists grouped by 3
# similar to the list L stated above
count = 0
while count < len(zp):
     current_img = zp[count]
     for rgb in current_img:
         red = int(rgb[0])
         green = int(rgb[1])
         blue = int(rgb[2])
```

So in this case lets say zp = L stated above. My code is spitting back out that

```
red = 2
green = 0
blue = 1
```

When I want my code to do this

```
red = 201
green = 304
blue = 514
```

Comment: Please give a sample for `masterL`.

Comment: masterL = ['201','304','514','312','143','224']

Comment: ```current_img``` is the first item in ```zp``` then you iterate over it.  Print ```current_img``` and ```rgb``` to see what is happening.

Comment: You need to increment `count`

Comment: Your `count < len(zp)` will always be true since neither count or zp changed in the loop

Comment: @wwii so atm when i print those things rgb = 201 and current_img = ['201','304','514']. I think I may have figured it out now

Comment: It's OK to post an answer to your own question - if you do, explain what was going wrong.

Comment: The [canonical way to iterate](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) over an iterable is: ```for thing in container:#do stuff with/to thing```

Answer (score 1):

@wwii Helped me understand that I went a step too far.

In order to get the result I wanted this is what my code should have looked like

```
# In the example above current_img would have looked like this
current_img = ['201', '304', '514']

# In order to get the output I wanted my code should have looked something like this
red = current_img[0]
green = current_img[1]
blue = current_img[2]
```

Comment: You also can get rid of the `while` `count` loop with `for current_img in zg`: